# BOOL method not returning YES inside of block

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, boolean, objective-c-blocks

I have created a new method which returns a BOOL, shown below.

```
+(BOOL)checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst:(PFUser *)opponentUser {
    // Find all the games where the current user is user1 and the opponentUser is user2
    PFQuery *currentUserIsUser1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Game"];
    [currentUserIsUser1 whereKey:kMESGameUser1 equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [currentUserIsUser1 whereKey:kMESGameUser2 equalTo:opponentUser];
    [currentUserIsUser1 whereKey:kMESGameIsActive equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [currentUserIsUser1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (objects) {
            // We have games where the current user is user1
            // NEED TO RETURN NO TO THIS METHOD AND NOT RUN FURTHER IN METHOD...
            NSLog(@"Results returned for existing game where current user is User1. Results: %@",objects);
        } else {
            // If there are no objects from first query and no error we run the second query
            if (!error) {
                // Find all the games where the current user is user2 and the opponentUser is user1
                PFQuery *currentUserIsUser2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Game"];
                [currentUserIsUser2 whereKey:kMESGameUser1 equalTo:opponentUser];
                [currentUserIsUser2 whereKey:kMESGameUser2 equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
                [currentUserIsUser2 whereKey:kMESGameIsActive equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
                [currentUserIsUser2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                    if (objects) {
                        // We have games where the current user is user2
                        // NEED TO RETURN NO TO THIS METHOD AND NOT RUN FURTHER IN METHOD...
                        NSLog(@"Results returned for existing game where current user is User2. Results: %@",objects);
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }];


    return NO;
}
```

The problem I have is how to return a YES value within a block within the method. 
See the sections in the method which say // NEED TO RETURN NO TO THIS METHOD AND NOT RUN FURTHER IN METHOD...
How can I return YES here. If I add return YES I get an incompatible pointer types error.

Further to this, once I have the method returning YES, how do I call this method and do something depending on the result. 
For example I need to call this method and if it is true then do something else, if not do nothing...

Comment: I suggest that you use a "success/fail" blocks as method params instead of returning a BOOL value, especially if you think that code inside your method will be executed async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, so here is a guess: you wish your block to return a value to `checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst`.

When a block in constructed it usually makes a *copy* of any value referenced from its environment. If you wish your block to *modify* a variable in its environment you must mark that variable with `__block`. In your code this would look something like:

```
__block BOOL blockStatus = YES;
[currentUserIsUser1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
 {
    ...
    blockStatus = NO;
 }
];

if (!blockStatus)
{
   ...
}
```

**Important:** The name of the method you are calling, `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, suggests that the block may not be called *synchronously*, which means the call may return before the block is executed. If this is the case you need to tackle the issue in a different way; which may involve calling a synchronous equivalent of `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` or modifying `checkIfGameAlreadyExistsAgainst` so that it accepts a block which it calls asynchronously with its result rather than returning a value directly.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, yes they are async so should be ok. I have added the update to a BOOL value inside the block then return this value at the end of the method which works ok.

Comment: @StuartM - if the block is called asynchronously then it is *not* ok as `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` may return *before* the block has been called, and then a following return statement will return the BOOL value before the block has had a chance to alter it. It will only work correctly if the block is called synchronously.

Comment: you are correct this is async therefore the return is returned before the block is run which is NOT what I want. Do you know if there is anything I can do to make this sync instead of async? I do not own the methods findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock, they are owned by Parse.com. Is there anything I can do to my own method to remedy this?

Comment: @StuartM - I've never used this package, but a quick scan of the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html) suggests `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` is the async version of `findObjects:`.

Comment: Would I then need to fire the findObjects on a background thread to ensure it does not lock the UI, but in turn does that make it async, I am unsure? But yes you are correct findObjects/countObjects are the normal sync options.

Comment: @StuartM - You might need to read up some more on concurrency. If you need this piece of your logic not to block the main thread you'll need to run it all on another thread, i.e. asynchronously with the main thread. You can't just run one method within your logic on another thread and stay synchronous - being synchronous means waiting (blocking) for the method to complete and it doesn't matter what thread that method is running on.